# Why does my working directory not function - R

Tags: r

I recently started using R, and it seems my working directories never work. I've been trying to simply turn a JSON document into a file on my desktop (to simplify things), but it does not do anything. The weird thing is that it also does not display an error message.

Could someone please help?

```
library ("jsonlite")
library ("ggplot2")
library ("stringr")
library ("arules")

setwd("~/Desktop")


tmp <- readLines("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
jsonLot <- fromJSON(tmp)

myjsonLot <- toJSON(jsonLot, pretty=TRUE)
print(myjsonLot)
View(myjsonLot)
fileConn <- file(paste0("~/Desktop", "Covid19_timeseries.json"))
writeLines(myjsonlot, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document is around 17mb. Since you are not manipulating it in any way, i would rather download it directly instead on trying to load it to memory:
Do

```
destination <- "~/Desktop/Covid19_timeseries.json"
download.file('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json', destination)
```